# a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in numpy.frombuffer

Tags: python, python-3.8

I ma using python 3.8
CODE:

```
import numpy as np 
s = 'Hello World' 
a = np.frombuffer(s, dtype = 'S1') 
print (a)
```

ERROR:

```
a = np.frombuffer(s, dtype = 'S1')

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: The error is quite self.-explanatory. Try ```b'Hello World' ```, putting a ```b``` before the string

Comment: Change `s = 'Hello World'` to `s = b'Hello World'`

Comment: Why are you trying to use `np.frombuffer`??? What is it you are trying to actually accopmlish? it isn't clear